# Blender Compositing view ( move left & right )

Tags: compositing-nodes

How can I go right and left after I zoomed in image part in Compositing view? [image]

Comment: You're in the compositing layout, but I'm pretty sure the window you're referring to is the UV Editor.

Answer (score 0):

In 2.82 you can move with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + middle click. Try that maybe?

Comment: mine is 2.79 and i try shif + middle click. but it not work